# How to design dynamic script generation as part of AJAX response?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, json

I am experimenting with a modular AJAX design where a script is returned to process and display payload. I currently have the following JSON response working but I would like some advice in terms of structuring the application to support this in a more maintainable way.

```
{
    payload: "<div class=\"test\">Something</div>",
    load: "jQuery(this.payload).appendTo('body')"
}
```

To generate the "load" script I have considered:

- Pass all dynamic variables via `this` and loading a fixed JavaScript from server

  ```
  jQuery(this.payload).appendTo(this.appendTo)
  ```
- Replace special templates within JavaScript with dynamic content:

  ```
  jQuery(this.payload).appendTo('{{APPENDTO}}')
  ```
- Or perhaps there would be a better methodology?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before I have had the following structure;

```
[
    {
        args: ["<div class=\"test\">Something</div>"],
        method: "appendTo",
        selector: "body"
    },
    ...
]
```

Which you could then do as;

```
var foo = JSON.parse(theJSON);

for (var i=0;i<foo.length;i++) {
    var curr = foo[i];
    jQuery.fn[method].apply($(curr.selector), curr.args);
}
```

This supports the most common DOM methods, but can also support `remove()`, `empty()` etc;

```
[
    {
        args: [],
        method: "remove",
        selector: ".someElement"
    },
    ...
]
```

If this is still too stringent, you should look at skipping JSON completely, and just inserting the response into your page as a `<script>` tag.

Comment: Adding this directly into a `<script>` tag makes quite a lot of sense. The only concern that I have is what is the best way to dynamically present a script? should I have a `template script` and replace all blanks from PHP script, or should the script be constructed by a PHP script? I don't like the idea of building custom scripts by PHP but aside from HEREDOC syntax, is there a "right" way of doing this? cheers Matt